# When to ignore code blocks for code coverage

Tags: c++, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have been tasked to increase code coverage of an existing CPP project.
I found some code blocks which I feel are dead code. However, since I am new to the project, I might have missed some corner cases. Hence, I am not sure if I should delete the code.

I found that there is a way to mark pieces of code so that they are'nt counted in the code coverage.
Is this a valid use-case for ignoring lines for code coverage tools?

Can someone post all the cases when one might want to use these annotations?

I know that it is valid for:

- ignoring generated files
- non logic code which isn't supposed to be hit

Comment: If you are not sure the code is really dead then you could put an `assert(0);` with an appropriate comment. This way you don't break anything in production but in debug code you will get a fatal error whenever that supposedly unreachable code is reached.
With such an assertion in place, it should be acceptable that the respective code is not covered.

Comment: @DanielJunglas If you turn that into an answer you can be sure of my upvote as soon as I notice. Of course, no guarantee on other voters ...